# C# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.'

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

## Information

Hello mates! Several days ago, I've ran into issue with **Selenium** and that is to be exact the error in the **title**. I have been trying to resolve this issue myself for some days now with no luck at all. Chrome is being run from **external** file, when I try to open **manually**, it **works**. If I try to run the driver from the **default** location, it **works**. I've tried different versions of Selenium with no luck and different versions of Chrome.

### Expected results

ChromeDriver **will** execute chrome.exe.

### Actual results

ChromeDriver **fails** to start chrome.exe for **unknown** reason.
[CLI Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee5WH.png)

## Code

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions { BinaryLocation = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"GoogleChromePortable") });
```

### Exception details

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at Self_Contained.Program.Main(String[] args) in *:\*\*\SFC\Program.cs:line 11
```

Comment: looks like you're giving it a bad path.  Build the string with your path.combine and check it first... You may also just want to create a new ChromeOptions object and use options.BinaryLocation = yourPath;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of research I found somewhere that **excluding** chrome.exe may lead to this issue. I added chrome.exe to the binary path and voilà it **is** working.